# Optional ofNullable execution flow in java 8

Tags: java, java-8

I have noticed that if I use Optional the following way:

```
Object returnValue = Optional.ofNullable(nullableValue)
         .map(nonNullValue -> firstMethod(arg1, nonNullValue))
         .orElse(secondMethod)
```

It is executing both the first method and second method when the nullableValue is not null. Am I doing something wrong? I want it to execute only firstMethod when nullableValue is not null.

map and flatMap seems to have preCondition ( `if(!isPresent()`). but, orElse doesn't. How can I write my code using java8 without using if not null condition?

Based on comments, *sample code*:

```
public static String firstMethod(String someString) {
        System.out.println("In first method");
        return someString;
    }

    public static String secondMethod() {
        System.out.println("In second method");
        return "secondMethod";
    }

    public static void main(String a[]) {
        String nullableString = "nonNullString";
        String result = Optional.ofNullable(nullableString)
                .map(nonNullString -> firstMethod(nonNullString))
                .orElse(secondMethod());
        System.out.println("Result: "+result);
    }
```

*Output:*

```
In first method
In second method
Result: nonNullString
```

Comment: What is `secondMethod`? It can't be a method and it can't be "executed".

Comment: I have added sample code. I might be using it completely wrong. Could you suggest what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Wow, the new optional class in java seems so cumbersome. Would you like to see my solution witgout the optional class? Or do you need to use optional for some sort of course?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are calling the second method to pass as a parameter to the `orElse()` call. The `orElse()` is not the one calling `secondMethod()` like what happens in the `map` call. You are passing the returned value from `secondMethod()` not the method itself.

What you want to do:

`Optional.ofNullable(nullableValue).map(MyClass::firstMethod).orElseGet(MyClass::secondMethod);`

What this does it is casts secondMethod into a supplier. That way it is only called when the optional is null.